# Two click sound when pedaling, chain delayed engagement

Tags: electric-bike, mechanical, giant

Hi All! New owner of Giant Explore E+ here.
Just into the first 100 miles. I noticed my bike is making a clicking sound when I start pedaling from static or freewheeling. This happens both when motor is on or off.
As in the video, when start pedaling, the first click sound didn't engage the chain with drivetrain, and the second sound start to engage (I start to feel normal resistance when rolling the bike).

The problem feels exactly the same as this post: https://www.emtbforums.com/threads/trance-e-2-knocking-when-pedaling-solved.2979/
I tried to lock the clutch as mentioned in the post above, but no fixed.

At first I thought this is a freehub/pawls issue. So I took off the rear wheel, and put my other bike's rear whell on it. Problem is the same. So I guess it's something else.
Any input will help. Thanks!

Comment: New bike always calls for the manufacturer/dealer to get this fixed, or at least provide a meaningful explanation.